# Using a canvas element as a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, textarea, ace-editor

I'm looking for a straight forward description of how to use a canvas element sort of like a text area.

I have seen projects such as [Ace](http://ace.ajax.org/). Just wondering how to go about writing to the area as if it where a textarea. Just plain text, nothing fancy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Output text, or allow users to actually write text? If the latter, why not use a textarea? If the first, why not use a div?

Comment: Ace, as I understand it, doesn't use `<canvas>`. It's predecessor, Bespin, did, but the creators gave it up as just too hard to get right. Text editing is widely considered an inappropriate use of the canvas element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ace used to be Mozilla Skywriter, which used to be Mozilla Bespin.

The code for Bespin is actually pretty simple to understand if you are willing to dig through it and make your own based on it, but it is sort of a fool's errand. The Canvas spec actually advises specifically against this:

> Authors should avoid implementing text
>   editing controls using the canvas
>   element. Doing so has a large number
>   of disadvantages:
>
> Mouse placement of the caret has to be
>   reimplemented.
>
> Keyboard movement of the caret has to
>   be reimplemented (possibly across
>   lines, for multiline text input).
>
> Scrolling of the text field has to be
>   implemented (horizontally for long
>   lines, vertically for multiline
>   input).
>
> Native features such as copy-and-paste
>   have to be reimplemented.
>
> Native features such as spell-checking
>   have to be reimplemented.
>
> Native features such as drag-and-drop
>   have to be reimplemented.
>
> Native features such as page-wide text
>   search have to be reimplemented.
>
> Native features specific to the user,
>   for example custom text services, have
>   to be reimplemented. This is close to 
>   impossible since each user might have
>   different services installed, and
>   there is an unbounded set of possible
>   such services.
>
> Bidirectional text editing has to be
>   reimplemented.
>
> For multiline text editing, line
>   wrapping has to be implemented for all
>   relevant languages.
>
> Text selection has to be
>   reimplemented.
>
> Dragging of bidirectional text
>   selections has to be reimplemented.
>
> Platform-native keyboard shortcuts
>   have to be reimplemented.
>
> Platform-native input method editors
>   (IMEs) have to be reimplemented.
>
> Undo and redo functionality has to be
>   reimplemented.
>
> Accessibility features such as
>   magnification following the caret or
>   selection have to be reimplemented.
>   This is a huge amount of work, and
>   authors are most strongly encouraged
>   to avoid doing any of it by instead
>   using the input element, the textarea
>   element, or the contenteditable
>   attribute.

Comment: I would like to allow for multiple selection like Sublime. I'm feeling it would be easier to start from scratch and build my own text input widget with Canvas than to somehow modify an existing text widget to allow this. Would you disagree?

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting the live demo with chrome shows they use divs and spans to achieve this. The blinking cursor is a div that seems to switch between hidden and visible on a regular basis. I would think that they just check the pressed key from the event and write it to the corresponding span for the line.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Its certainly given me some ideas. How do you think they achieve the placing of the cursor within a particular div/span, at a certain point in the text? And for that matter, re edit a particular div/span element?

Comment: I have had another look and there seems to be a textarea involved as well. Looks like the textarea is moved where you click and you type in the textarea which then is moved. I typed into the window and saw the element.style attributes increase for the attribute left. It certainly takes a lot of fiddeling to get that working.