# Canvas-based editor - How?

Tags: javascript, html, text, canvas, text-editor

I've been trying to develop a text-editor (as a personal project) using HTML5 canvas, but I've encountered problems with implementing copy / paste / backspace functionality. I've studied the source code for about half-a-dozen projects much like this one, but I still haven't found a solution.

Can anyone recommend a fast, efficient way to implement this sort of functionality?

Comment: Short answer, don't. Canvas is wholly inappropriate for use as a text editor. See [Simon Sarris's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336243/using-a-canvas-element-as-a-textarea/6345055#6345055)

Comment: As I said, it's a personal project, so it doesn't really matter if it's a good idea or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use such way: focus is in hidden textarea, so ctrl-v works properly. On text change you change your canvas image. You can easy synchronize selection. You can bind textarea "input" event to catch all changes:

> **Input**: This event is sent when a user enters text in a textbox. This event is only called when the text displayed would change, thus it is not called when the user presses non-displayable keys.

I think, this is the best and the only right way (you can't work with clipboard in javascript without it)

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden textarea"? Should I set the CSS property display:hidden; ? Can I do it without adding textarea to element tree?